# Use Aggregate Function in UNION ALL result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I use aggregate Functions in UNION ALL Resultset

FOR EXAMPLE

```
SELECT A,B FROM MyTable
UNION ALL
SELECT B,C FROM MYAnotherTable
```

Result Set Would Be

```
    A  B
--------------
    1  2
    3  4
    4  5
    6  7
```

When I tried to get `MAX(A)` it returns `3`. I want `6`.

When I tried to get `MAX(B)` it returns `4`. I want `7`.

Other than `Max()`, Can I get another aggregate function which user defined?

For example:

(`SELECT TOP 1 A WHERE B=5`)

Real Case [Here](http://pastie.org/8124275)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select max(A)
from(
      SELECT A,B FROM MyTable
      UNION ALL
      SELECT B,C FROM MYAnotherTable
    ) Tab
```

### SQL Fiddle [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a790c/1/0)

If the column `A` is varchar (You said that in the comment below) try this way:

```
select max(A)
from(
      SELECT cast(A as int) as A,B FROM MyTable
      UNION ALL
      SELECT B,C FROM MYAnotherTable
    ) Tab
```

With `TOP 1`

```
select max(A)
from(
      SELECT top 1 cast(A as int) as A,B FROM MyTable
      UNION ALL
      SELECT B,C FROM MYAnotherTable
    ) Tab
```

Comment: I tried the same already. I also want to do group by to the resultset after Union all. Max(a) is always returning the Max(A) not max of A And B

Comment: I'm sorry! the column was varchar(200)

Comment: maybe use a faux column value: `select max(A)
from(
      SELECT A,B, 'View1' as View FROM MyTable
      UNION ALL
      SELECT B,C, 'View2' as View FROM MYAnotherTable
    ) Tab GROUP BY Tab.View`

Comment: In example, its column A. Now I fixed the issue made it to MAX(0+A).

Comment: Another Question! Can I get another column (aggregate) in result set with condition (SELECT TOP 1 A WHERE B=4).

Comment: Can I create such a user defined aggregate function?

Comment: @Parado I want to get it along with the aggregate function, MAX(A),MAX(B),MyCondition

Comment: @Parado I changed my question so. please add it your answer

Comment: @Parado Should I revert my question?

Comment: Question already in stackO and answer says "You cannot write custom aggregates outside of the CLR". So I have to create another Aggregate function and call it in my SP . Rite?

Comment: @Parado The procedure seems to be a difficult one. please help me to do this. This is my real problem.

Comment: @Parado I want to get max(A) , Max(b), (SELECT TOP 1 A WHERE B=5)

Comment: being more precise, its Max(A), Max(B),(SELECT TOP 1 A WHERE B=MAX(A)). Or simply, I want to select the complete row where the value Max(A) lies @Parado

Comment: For example, Max(A) will give 6. I want to get the value of B where Max(A)=A ie 7 @Parado

Comment: @Parado I already asked a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548743/select-complete-row-where-maxcolumn-in-group-by But the question doesn't make any sense and will be closed by the community soon I think

Answer (score 0):

```sql
CREATE TABLE    #Transaction (
                TransactionID INT, 
                ProductID INT, 
                TransactionDate datetime
)
INSERT INTO     #Transaction (
                TransactionID, 
                ProductID,
                TransactionDate
)
SELECT          TransactionID, 
                ProductID,
                TransactionDate
FROM            [Production].[TransactionHistoryArchive]
UNION
SELECT          TransactionID, 
                ProductID,
                TransactionDate
FROM            [Production].[TransactionHistory]
```

Comment: please add description to this how should execute these queries

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
DECLARE @a TABLE (a int, b int)
INSERT @a 
VALUES (1,2), (3,4)
DECLARE @b TABLE (b int, c int)
INSERT @b 
VALUES (4, 5),(6,7)

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT A,B FROM @a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT B AS A,C AS B FROM @b
) SELECT MAX (a), MAX(b)

FROM cte
```