# SELECT Row Values WHERE MAX() is Column Value In GROUP BY Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I select like this? Can I create a User defined Aggregate Function

`SELECT Max(A),(SELECT TOP 1 FROM TheGroup Where B=Max(A))` FROM MyTable

where MyTable as Shown Below

```
    A  B  C
--------------
    1  2  S
    3  4  S
    4  5  T
    6  7  T
```

I want a Query Like this

```
SELECT MAX(A),(B Where A=Max(A)),C FROM MYTable GROUP BY C
```

I'm Expecting the result as below

```
 MAX(A)  Condition    C
-----------------------
   3        4         S
   6        7         T
```

Comment: what do you want your result to be ?

Comment: You can't do `SELECT TOP 1` without specifying a value/values.

Comment: @bendataclear I know. I just expressed my requirement

Comment: you're going to have to either describe what you want in plain english, or give some example results, or this question is never going to get an answer...

Comment: @StevieG I added the expected answer to the Question

Comment: he needs the last row (6,7) as the result

Comment: ok, so in your results, B!=Max(A), so its still not clear what you're trying to do... Do you mean you want the entire row where A=Max(A) ?

Comment: @StevieG he wants all the columns in the row containing the max value for column A

Comment: @Andy I'm not sure, cause my answer that does exactly that got downvoted

Comment: Sorry, but you're changing your question too much; -1

Comment: I think just stop guessing until he can clearly explain what he needs.

Comment: @OzrenTkalčecKrznarić Ya I did it to make the Question more Clear. But I hope now its better and clear.

Comment: @bendataclear I hope its clear Now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following Query :

```
SELECT TABLE1.A , TABLE2.B , TABLE1.C
FROM 
(
    SELECT MAX(A) AS A,C 
    FROM MYTable 
    GROUP BY C
) AS TABLE1 
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT *
FROM MYTable
) AS TABLE2 ON TABLE1.A = TABLE2.A
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae901/3)

you can do it by simple join query . join query always run faster then In query . Join query run only one time at the time of execution of the query . we can archive same result by using IN query .

Answer (score 2):

```
 SELECT A,B,C FROM
     (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C ORDER BY A DESC) RN FROM MyTable)
 WHERE RN = 1
```

(this query will always return only one row per C value)

OR

```
WITH CTE_Group AS 
(
    SELECT C, MAX(A) AS MaxA
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY C
)
SELECT g.MaxA, t.B, g.C
FROM MyTable t
INNER JOIN CTE_Group g ON t.A = g.MaxA AND t.C = g.C
```

(if there are multiple rows that have same Max(A) value - this query will return all of them)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Max(A)
FROM MyTable
Where B=(SELECT Max(A) FROM MyTable)
```

update:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
Where B=(SELECT Max(A) FROM MyTable)
```

update 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, B
FROM MyTable
Where A=(SELECT Max(A) FROM MyTable GROUP BY C)
```

update 3:

ok, I think I understand what you're looking for now.. How about this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
Where A in (SELECT Max(A) FROM MyTable GROUP BY C)
```

Comment: @Luv No, I want the Max(A) Along with the complete row where the condition A=Max(A)

Comment: As much sense as the original requirement.

Comment: @StevieG GROUP BY aggregates the function. How  could I implement it there?

Comment: You only need to use GROUP BY if you have an aggregate function in the select clause, which I don't. you probably want DISTINCT.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM YourTable t1 
Left Outer Join YourTable t2 on t1.C=t2.C AND t1.A < t2.A
WHERE t2.A is null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
  cte AS
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cola desc) AS Rno,
    *
  FROM
    tbl
)
SELECT top 1
cola,colb
FROM
  cte
order by Rno
```

Then try it:

```
    WITH
  cte AS
(
  SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col3 ORDER BY col1 desc) AS Rno,
    *
  FROM
    tbl

)
SELECT 
col1,col2,col3
FROM
  cte
WHERE Rno=1
```

Comment: @Subin Jacob Try the above query

Comment: I want to GROUP BY. I updated the Question. Please check it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM MyTable    
    WHERE A IN (SELECT MAX(A) FROM MyTable GROUP BY C)
```

Comment: This Would work I think. But the Query have to access the table twice. In this example its k, but in real I got that table by INNER JOIN ing many other tables. So I have to do it twice. Unwanted Code rite?

Comment: this will give incorrect results for cases when values of A are repeated in different groups, like: [A,B,C]={(1,2,3),(4,5,3),(4,2,4),(5,2,4)]